# Wordpress transfer problems Cant' find variable jQuery

Tags: hosting, migration

When I move WP site from 1 host to another. Normally I do this:

1. Export database with PHPMyadmin
2. Download files with FileZilla ftp
3. Import Database to new database
4. Upload files with FileZilla ftp
5. Make a Search 'old string' and Replace 'new string' [Database Search and Replace Script in PHP](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/)

And normally the site is up and running. However lately when I follow these steps this error occured:

[image: Error in Console after transfer site]

To fix this I can download a new wordpress installation from [Download Wordpress](https://nl.wordpress.org/download/)

And then it works again.. but is there another solution? Or does someone has any experience with this error?

Answer (score 0):

Well I've never faced this issue but here is worthy suggestion as per my experience. If your website is running fine before migration, then you can use [Duplicator](https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/) migration plugin which is very easy & useful for migration. It will never produce any this type of error.

Comment: I think that is a great solution.. but the above described behaviour is really strange

Comment: I think you have used caching plugin or minified assets from any plugins that misbehave here.